# Azure blob storage with Asp.net Core web app

Tags: azure-storage

I am trying to create a new web app which would upload files to azure blob storage. According to the following article, I should see "Cloud storage with Azure Storage" in "Connected Services" in visual studio 2017.  But I don't see the option. I have the "Azure development" components installed for visual studio 2017. Anyone else faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I should see "Cloud storage with Azure Storage" in "Connected Services" in visual studio 2017. But I don't see the option.

I created a ASP.NET Core web app using Visual studio 2017 preview (version 15.3.0) and try to find **Microsoft Azure storage Connected Service**, but as you said, it can not be found in search results.

***Connected Services:***

[image]

***Search results:***

[image]

You can give a feedback on [Visual studio UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).

Besides, you can manually install [Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)  and configure your project to consume Azure Storage services.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fred. Yes. I had already implemented it using the storage libraries. But was just wondering why that option was not available. Note, its available for a MVC app created with .Net framework(on the same VS2017). So just wondering if the above is some kind of limitation.